# LocalStorage Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, local-storage

According to everything I've read, Firefox 3.5+ supports localStorage. And yet I'm seeing the alert (failing) in Firefox 3.6. Do I have some strange settings in my Firefox? Any ideas?

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch (e) {
        alert('failing');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: The page has an HTML5 doctype (though I think this makes no difference).

Comment: Your code works fine for me. You should include the value of "e" in your alert, of course.

Comment: So it's some strange setting in my version of Firefox? I suppose that's alright, then. I'll try adding `e`.

Comment: `e` is `[Exception... "Security error"  code: "1000" nsresult: "0x805303e8 (NS_ERROR_DOM_SECURITY_ERR)"  location: "http://[domain name elided]/public/javascripts/switch_style.js Line: 18"]`

Comment: A bit of googling on the error number fixed it. In `about:config` I had `dom.storage.enabled` set to `false`. I don't recall doing that. It may be something to do with NoScript (though javascript was enabled).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though Firefox supports localStorage, it can be turned off. Check that it is turned on.

Go to `about:config` and check that `dom.storage.enabled` is set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the bug described at http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2012/04/25/firefox-failing-localstorage/: Firefox disallows local storage if you have your cookie options set to "Ask every time".  Strange but true, at least in FF12 that I was using at the time.  Workaround is to set your cookies to keep for session or until they expire.