# how to empty firefox dom localstorage

Tags: firefox, local-storage

I'm trying to [clear my local storage in Firefox 13.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392659/lawnchair-nuke-not-working-after-filling-my-storage-quota) so I can continue using Lawnchair.

In Firebug [Dom] tab, I have been [manually deleting properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6130392/194309) from `'localstorage'` key, but it takes about 10 seconds per delete (only 454 * 10 seconds to go!).  (I hoped I could release enough space to let Lawnchair.nuke() do its job, but haven't been able to so far.)

I tried visiting [about:config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3840119/194309) to turn off and back on localstorage but that didn't delete what was in there.

How can I mass-delete local storage for one website in Firefox?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open the built-in console, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (it's faster than Firebug), and paste the following code:

```js
while (localStorage.length) localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(0));
```

This snippet will delete **all** localStorage key-value pairs on the given website.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit [**`localstorage.clear()`**](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-clear) should also do the same thing.

Comment: now, when I do that in Firefox 26 there is error in console: "Error: The operation is insecure."

Answer (score 11):

```
localStorage.clear(); // Capital S is required.
```

This will [clear all key-value pairs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-clear).

Comment: Awesome one thing though. Make sure you put a capital S or it won't work.